# Laravel - Testing Auth0 User

Tags: laravel, auth0

I have a Laravel application with a standard User table that I'm implementing Auth0 login to. On login, a user record is created in the database with the given email.

I have a CustomUserRepository.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class CustomUserRepository implements \Auth0\Laravel\Contract\Auth\User\Repository
{
    public function fromSession(array $user): ?\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
    {
        return User::firstOrCreate(['email' => $user['email']]);
    }

    public function fromAccessToken(array $user): ?\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
    {
        // Simliar to above. Used for stateless application types.
        return null;
    }

    public function getUserByUserInfo(array $userinfo) : Authenticatable
    {
        $user = $this->upsertUser( $userinfo['profile'] );
        return new Auth0User( $user->getAttributes(), $userinfo['accessToken'] );
    }

    protected function upsertUser($profile)
    {
        return User::firstOrCreate(
            [
                'sub' => $profile['sub']
            ],
            [
                'email' => $profile['email'] ?? '',
                'name' => $profile['name'] ?? '',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

And my auth.php file:

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard'     => 'auth0',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'auth0' => [
            'driver' => 'auth0',
            'provider' => 'auth0',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'auth0' => [
            'driver' => 'auth0',
            'repository' => App\Repositories\CustomUserRepository::class
        ],
    ],
```

The app works. I login with Auth0, the users are created, everything works entirely as expected, except for the testing.

```
        $this->be(User::find(1));
        $response = $this->get('/valid-url');
        $response->assertStatus(200);

        $response = $this->get('/another-valid-url');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
```

In this case, PHPUnit seems to "forget" my login for the second get() request. The first one works fine, status 200, everything OK. With the second request (get or post) I always get a 302 back to the login page.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

#on your login function there should be the following

```
    if(auth()->attempt($formFields)){
        $request->session()->regenerate();
```

Comment: I'm not quite following in which file that needs to go - the actual login itself is almost entirely dealt with by the Auth0 Laravel package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).